# More efficient way to make a string in a string of just words

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, replace

I am making an application where I will be fetching tweets and storing them in a database. I will have a column for the complete text of the tweet and another where only the words of the tweet will remain (I need the words to calculate which words were most used later).

How I currently do it is by using 6 different `.replaceAll()` functions which some of them might be triggered twice. For example I will have a for loop to remove every "hashtag" using `replaceAll()`.

The problem is that I will be editing as many as thousands of tweets that I fetch every few minutes and I think that the way I am doing it will not be too efficient.

**What my requirements are in this order (also written in comments down bellow):**

1. Delete all usernames mentioned
2. Delete all RT (retweets flags)
3. Delete all hashtags mentioned
4. Replace all break lines with spaces
5. Replace all double spaces with single spaces
6. Delete all special characters except spaces

**Here is a Short and Compilable Example:**

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String text = "RT @AshStewart09: Vote for Lady Gaga for \"Best Fans\""
                + " at iHeart Awards\n"
                + "\n"
                + "RT!!\n"
                + "\n"
                + "My vote for #FanArmy goes to #LittleMonsters #iHeartAwards"
                + " htt…";

        String[] hashtags = {"#FanArmy", "#LittleMonsters", "#iHeartAwards"};
        System.out.println("Before: " + text + "\n");

        // Delete all usernames mentioned (may run multiple times)
        text = text.replaceAll("@AshStewart09", "");
        System.out.println("First Phase: " + text + "\n");

        // Delete all RT (retweets flags)
        text = text.replaceAll("RT", "");
        System.out.println("Second Phase: " + text + "\n");

        // Delete all hashtags mentioned
        for (String hashtag : hashtags) {
            text = text.replaceAll(hashtag, "");
        }
        System.out.println("Third Phase: " + text + "\n");

        // Replace all break lines with spaces
        text = text.replaceAll("\n", " ");
        System.out.println("Fourth Phase: " + text + "\n");

        // Replace all double spaces with single spaces
        text = text.replaceAll(" +", " ");
        System.out.println("Fifth Phase: " + text + "\n");

        // Delete all special characters except spaces 
        text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", "").trim();
        System.out.println("Finaly: " + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to split the strings into words by whitespace before doing the replace code? Then run a match filter on each word separately.

Comment: Some of your patterns can be joined in one, for example `"#FanArmy|#LittleMonsters|#iHeartAwards"`

Comment: @Salauyou I edited my code to better portray how the hashtags would be handled in my main application.

Comment: I see... let me explain one performance issue. As you know, in Java, `String` objects are immutable, so every new string that differs at least 1 char from old one, must be another object--so operations for allocation memory and creating object are executed.

Comment: But! `replaceAll` method doesn't use strings internally, it performs operation on `StringBuilder` object, which is mutable, so every altering operation is much cheaper. As I mentioned, you can combine substrings to be replaced into one regex pattern--you can do it in `for` loop, and apply this combined pattern to your string just one time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @M42 Sorry I didn't know there was a different place for these kind of questions. I'll post it there then.

Comment: @M42: That's a pure non-sense. The OP wasn't seeking a code-review, they were obviously asking a performance question. The fact that they presented some code doesn't qualify it for code review. Moreover, it was an example code, not a real one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on `replaceAll` is probably the biggest performance killer as it compiles the regex again and again. The use of regexes for everything is probably the second most significant problem.

Assuming all usernames start with `@`, I'd replace

```
// Delete all usernames mentioned (may run multiple times)
text = text.replaceAll("@AshStewart09", "");
```

by a loop copying everything until it founds a `@`, then checking if the following chars match any of the listed usernames and possibly skipping them. For this lookup you could use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). A simpler method would be a [replaceAll](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29)-like loop for the regex `#\w+` together with a `HashMap` lookup.

```
// Delete all RT (retweets flags)
text = text.replaceAll("RT", "");
```

Here,

```
private static final Pattern RT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("RT");
```

is a sure win. All the following parts could be handled similarly. Instead of

```
// Delete all special characters except spaces 
text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", "").trim();
```

you could use Guava's [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html). The method `removeFrom` does exactly what you did, but `collapseFrom` or `trimAndCollapseFrom` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

According to the now closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131449/what-would-be-preferred-aesthetically-and-performance-wise?noredirect=1), it all boils down to

```
tweet = tweet.replaceAll("@\\w+|#\\w+|\\bRT\\b", "")
                .replaceAll("\n", " ")
                .replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N} ]+", " ")
                .replaceAll(" +", " ")
                .trim();
```

The second line seems to be redundant as the third one does remove `\n` too. Changing the first line's replacement to `" "` doesn't change the outcome an allows to aggregate the replacements.

```
tweet = tweet.replaceAll("@\\w*|#\\w*|\\bRT\\b|[^@#\\p{L}\\p{N} ]+", " ")
                .replaceAll(" +", " ")
                .trim();
```

I've changed the usernames and hashtags part to eating also lone `#` or `@`, so that it doesn't need to be consumed by the special chars part. This is necessary for corrent processing of strings like `!@AshStewart09`.

For maximum performance, you surely need a precompiled pattern. I'd also re-suggest to use Guava's `CharMatcher` for the second part. Guava is huge (2 MB I guess), but you surely find more useful things there. So in the end you can get

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("@\\w*|#\\w*|\\bRT\\b|[^@#\\p{L}\\p{N} ]+");
private static final CharMatcher CHAR_MATCHER = CharMacher.is(" ");

tweet = PATTERN.matcher(tweet).replaceAll(" ");
tweet = CHAR_MATCHER.trimAndCollapseFrom(tweet, " ");
```

Comment: I already did what you have in the second code snippet, I pretty much made everything a space in one `replaceAll` and then removed all the extra spaces. About the lone `#` and `@` what is the problem with leaving them get eaten by the `[\\p{L}\\p{N} ]+`? I mean the user can definitely have something like `!@AshStewart09` and it won't be a username since I' pretty sure it won't count as a username for tweeter itself either. Also one quick question, does `static` work as it works in C++ where it will define the object once and only once?

Comment: I wanted to do what you did, and you replace `!@AshStewart09` first by `!` and then by a blank. To preserve this, I can't let the second part of the regex eat the `@`. No idea how twitter works.

Comment: Yes, a `static` field in Java exists only once per class and gets initialized when the class gets loaded (i.e., practically only once, or never if you don't use the class :D).

Comment: @SilliconTouch the `static` in Java is not as flexible as in C++, you cannot apply it on local variables, but on fields they work the same as @maaartinus mentioned. (And probably the static nested classes are not available in C++, while they are in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

You can inline all of the things that are being replaced with nothing into one call to replace all and everything that is replaced with a space into one call like so (also using a regex to find the hashtags and usernames as this seems easier):

```
text = text.replaceAll("@\w+|#\w+|RT", "");
text = text.replaceAll("\n| +", " ");
text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", "").trim();
```